# Redirecting naked domains to www in Meteor with Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'd like to auto-redirect users who enter the naked domain for my site over to the www subdomain. Pre-Blaze, here's the code I was using to do this with Iron Router:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
    var rootDomainRegex = new RegExp(
        '^https:\\/\\/mysite.com',
        'ig'
    );
    if ( window && rootDomainRegex.test( window.location.href ) ) {
        this.stop();
        window.location = window.location.href.replace(
            rootDomainRegex,
            'https://www.mysite.com'
        );
    }
};
```

This stopped working when I upgraded to Meteor 0.8.0 and the Blaze-compatible version of Iron Router. (I replaced this.stop() with pause(), but that didn't help.) Now the page simply hangs when you navigate to the naked domain, with no console errors.

Does anyone have a reliable and Blaze-compatible way to redirect users from a naked domain over to www? (Or maybe this shouldn't be at the app level at all?)

Here's my post-Blaze code. (This is the code that's currently not working.)

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function(pause) {

    var rootDomainRegex = new RegExp(
        '^https:\\/\\/mysite.com',
        'ig'
    );
    rootDomainRegex.lastIndex = 0;
    if ( window && rootDomainRegex.test( window.location.href ) ) {
        window.location = window.location.href.replace(
            rootDomainRegex,
            'https://www.mysite.com'
        );
        pause();
    }

});
```

Edit with just a bit of extra info: I've just discovered that with the naked domain, the function passed to `Router.onBeforeAction()` simply doesn't run at all.

Comment: If you run Meteor behind an NGINX reverse proxy, it is pretty easy to do the domain redirects in Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

You should've pasted the updated code, where you've replaced this.stop with pause.

I doubt there's anything blaze-related to your code, it should just work and you should be redirected even if you don't call pause. So it probably is because your regex is not matching.

I guess you tried to call `console.log(rootDomainRegex.test(window.location.href))` before the `if` statement and it returned `true`?! If you did, that's the cause, the first time you call regex.test, it matches returning true, but also increases lastIndex on the regex - because of the `g` flag, the second time you call `test` it tries to match from that lastIndex and it fails, never executing the `window.location` part.

HTH, try to paste the exact code you have now not working if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited to add the currently live code. The regex isn't being `test()`ed anywhere else, but just for safety I added a `lastIndex` reset. That didn't help though.